# Values are not sent with ajax to mysql

Tags: mysql, ajax, filter, uislider

Please help, Variables Min and Max are not being sent to getData.php where filtering with MYSQL query is done.
The variables are displayed in #range and #range2 on index page.

Could you also give comments on the method that is used under "// Updating table data", for example would this be more appropriate:
    success:function(data)
       {
        $('#result').html(data);
       }

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#slider" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 50,
                max: 300,
                value: [ 60 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    var min = ui.value;
                    $('#range').text(min);
                }
            });
            $( "#slider2" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 50,
                max: 300,
                value: [ 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    var max = ui.value;
                    $('#range2').text(max);
                }
            }); 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {min:min,max:max},
                success: function(response){
    // Updating table data
                    $('#emp_table tr:not(:first)').remove();
                    $('#emp_table').append(response);   
                }      
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables min and max are only persisted in anonymous functions for slide. To persist them, define them outside the slide: function() block:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var min = undefined;
            var max = undefined;
            $( "#slider" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 50,
                max: 300,
                value: [ 60 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    min = ui.value;
                    $('#range').text(min);
                }
            });
            $( "#slider2" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 50,
                max: 300,
                value: [ 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    max = ui.value;
                    $('#range2').text(max);
                }
            }); 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {min:min,max:max},
                success: function(response){
    // Updating table data
                    $('#emp_table tr:not(:first)').remove();
                    $('#emp_table').append(response);   
                }      
            });
        });
</script>
```

To comment on your `remove/append` vs `html()`, either way is fine

Comment: Thank you for the response, however something is still wrong, variables dont get their new value and remain undefined.
Notice: Undefined index: min in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\tests\

Comment: If I change the variables from undefined to some numbers, results get filtered accordingly, so the rest is fine.